# What does "Sound Check" in iPod settings do?

Tags: iphone, ipod, settings

On my iPhone (though I'm sure it's on iPods and iPads as well), under the iPod settings, there's a toggle "Sound Check". What does it do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It enables what basically is just normalization. It scans the library for track volume information, and updates the normalization metadata if necessary. It also honors it, of course.